# Filling a DataSet manually

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, dataset

Let's say I have a DataSet defined as "ReportDataSet.xsd" with a single table called "employee". How do I go about filling this in Manually so I can return the filled DataSet to another function that'll use it to generate a report? Here's what I'm doing right now, but I'm not sure if it's right.

```
ReportDataSet ds = new ReportDataSet();

ReportDataSet.employeeRow empRow = ds.employee.AddemployeeRow(
   employeeId, name, dateOfBirth, Address, Phone
);

return ds;
```

**Here's the issue:**
I debug it and can see the data in VS2010's debugger results view, but the crystal report I generate using the DataSet (below) always comes out as blank.

```
EmployeeReport rpt = new EmployeeReport(); //EmployeeReport.rpt
ReportDataSet rds = GetDataSet();
rpt.Load();
rpt.SetDataSource(rds);
```

I'm not using a viewer and write the report to PDF right away. The resulting PDF has the template (images, etc), but no data.

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream("c:\\quote.pdf", FileMode.CreateNew);
using (fStream)
{
   MemoryStream oStream = (MemoryStream)rpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
   byte[] data = oStream.ToArray();
   fStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Comment: Do you receive errors of any kind?  What is causing you to think this is wrong is there no data showing on the report?

Comment: Are you sure that you are setting the Report Data source correctly to this DataSet? Might show that code as well.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 i think so. i simply get the dataset from the function and then call SetDataSource on the report object.

Comment: Ok just checking all parts of the equation here.  Taking a look at your edits now.

Comment: Have you tried calling rpt.DataBind(); after setting your source.

Comment: Excuse me I mean when you set the vier report source to your report do you call databind();

Comment: @Bearcat9425 i'm not actually using a viewer at all. i just export it to pdf straight away. i've added that part of the code to my original post as well so you can take a look at it. that's pretty much all of it. perhaps this is where the problem lies?

Comment: Is there a reason you are setting empRow you can just call that method explicitly,  I would try to do a ds.AcceptChanges() after you add your row as well then return ds.

Comment: I have this problem, but I'm importing data from a XML, if the table is not declared in the XML, the child of that table makes everything disapear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was caused by a discrepancy in the data I was using to fill in the DataSet (foreign key). I double checked the constraints and everything worked fine.